# writetextasync doesnt write all text to a file

Tags: c#, windows-8

So I want to create a simple text file with this code.
But when I open the created file , the text is not displayed entirely,
the only text I got is from tb1.text (id[2]).

Is there anything wrong here?

```
        private async void Save_Reg() 
        {
                var myfile = (tb3.Text+".xml");
                var folderUsed = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                var folderOp = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting;
                var createFile = await folderUsed.CreateFileAsync(myfile, folderOp);


                var password = tb2.Text;
                var recov = tb1.Text;
                string[] id = { myfile,password, recov };
                await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(createFile, id[0]);
                await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(createFile, id[1]);
                await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(createFile, id[2]);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there anything wrong here?

Yes. [`WriteTextAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh701508) *replaces* the contents of the current file. It's equivalent to the synchronous [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) method. If you want to *append*, you'll need [`AppendTextAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.appendtextasync.aspx).

Alternatively, concatenate the ids so you know the full contents you want to write, and then call `WriteTextAsync` just once.